# Customizing Stamping Functionality in Mozilla PDF.js Library

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf.js

We are currently using the Mozilla PDF.js library to implement PDF viewing functionality in our application. Our requirement is to customize the stamping feature in PDF.js to include predefined images such as "Approve," "Done," and "Rejected."

We've reviewed the documentation [Reference link](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/legacy/web/viewer.html) and are aware of the capability to upload images as stamps. However, we need guidance on how to integrate our custom predefined stamping images.

1. How can we add custom predefined stamping images to the PDF.js stamping functionality?
2. What modifications are required in the code to enable users to select and apply predefined stamps like "Approve," "Done," and "Rejected"?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.